# Why does this code NOT display Google.com

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, nsurl

I have an existing app that currently has embedded help files; I am trying to change them so they go to the internet for the localized help files.  This is my code:

```
//  make the popover
UIViewController* popoverContent = [UIViewController new];
UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 450, 500)];
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:(CGFloat)1.0 alpha:(CGFloat)1.0];  //  frame color?
popoverContent.view = popoverView;

//resize the popover view shown in the current view to the view's size
popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(450, 500);

NSURL *indexURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"];

//  add the UIWebView for RichText
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:popoverView.frame];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  //  change background color here

//  add the webView to the popover
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:indexURL]]; //  load it...
[popoverView addSubview:webView];

//  if previous popoverController is still visible... dismiss it
if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

//create a popover controller to display the HELP text
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)boHelpGeneralSetup).frame inView:self.view
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

This code works when the help file is embedded; why is it not working when I try to get the file from a web page on the internet?

Comment: When which file is embedded?

Comment: A HTML file containing the *exact* verbiage that is on the web page.  It's not relative to the question.

Comment: try to include the whole address with http://

Comment: @Mr.T that did it!  (and I knew that which makes it even more embarrasing!)  Please rewrite your comment as the answer, and I'll mark it so you get the points.  Thanks very much...  SD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Documentation:

> An NSURL object is composed of two parts—a potentially nil base URL
>   and a string that is resolved relative to the base URL. An NSURL
>   object is considered absolute if its string part is fully resolved
>   without a base; all other URLs are considered relative.
>
> For example, when constructing an NSURL object, you might specify
>   file:///path/to/web_root/ as the base URL and folder/file.html as the
>   string part, as follows:

In your case google.com is considered as string part but not base address. As address starts with http, you need to include the full path of the url.

So , it will be:

```
  NSURL *indexURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
```

Comment: You are welcome!!! Make sure you use https instead of http. Apple made users to use https from ios9 onwards.